# How can I extract 'stackoverflow.com' from it?

Tags: sql-server, regex, replace, find

In SQL Server, I've a table name URL_DATA with two column Domain and URL. Column URL contains address of different site for example "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask". How can I extract "stackoverflow.com" from it? OR How can I copy string "stackoverflow.com" in new column Domain?

```
Input Table:

| Domain |                      URL                             |
| ------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
|        | https://www.youtube.com/                             |
|        | https://www.youtube.com/feed/library                 |
|        | https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training|
|        | https://internshala.com/student/dashboard            |
|        | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask              |

Expected Output Table:

| Domain            |                      URL                             |
| ----------------- | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| youtube.com       | https://www.youtube.com/                             |
| youtube.com       | https://www.youtube.com/feed/library                 |
| red-gate.com      | https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-training|
| internshala.com   | https://internshala.com/student/dashboard            |
| stackoverflow.com | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask              |
```

I have tired using this:

update URL_DATA set domain = replace(replace(replace(domain,'',''),'https://',''),'www.','');

But unable to remove trailing characters.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support Regex; at least not natively (you could use a CLR function though). One example, however, is not really enough for us to really give an answer. At best, I would suggest finding the position of the 3rd forward slash (`/`) and returning that many left characters. But that assumes every value starts with `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: Please rephrase your question by showing several examples of URLs, along with the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this and it worked.

DECLARE @N2 VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @N1 INT;
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR SELECT Domain FROM URL_DATA ;
OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @N2
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
UPDATE URL_DATA SET Domain = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@N2,'http://',''),'https://',''),'www.','') where CURRENT OF C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @N2
END
CLOSE C1
OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @N2
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @N1= CHARINDEX('/',@N2)
IF (@N1>0)
BEGIN
UPDATE URL_DATA SET Domain = SUBSTRING(@N2,1,ABS(CHARINDEX('/',@N2)-1)) where CURRENT OF C1
END
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @N2
END
CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE  C1;